# Impedir que un elemento se pueda draggear si el contenido esta abierto - Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

tengo una lista de tarjetas que se pueden arrastrar usando la función de drag and drop de Angular Material.
Si haces click en una de las tarjetas, se despliega un menú (con más elementos dentro)

[Ejemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMPLg.png)

El caso es que puedo arrastrar estas tarjetas con el contenido abierto o cerrado. Sin embargo, yo no quiero que se pueda arrastrar si el contenido está abierto. Quiero que el contenido se cierre automáticamente o que en todo caso me impide el drag de las tarjetas abiertas.
Sé que podría usar una condición booleana pero no estoy seguro de cómo implementarla. ¿Me podrían ayudar?
¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Para deshabilitar el drag puedes usar la propiedad `[cdkDragDisabled]="condicion para deshabilitarlo"` en el elemento que tengas aplicada la directiva `cdkDrag`.  // Y otra cosa, cuando hagas una pregunta, por favor intenta añadir al menos la parte del código afectada para que sea más fácil ayudarte. slds

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.